# What is "mId" (unknown alien variable) in some code from google on notifications, it is a mystery

Tags: android, android-notifications

does anyone know what how to use the "mId" variable in code provided by google?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

It is not explained in the documentation. but appears as the last line in the code.  when am using this code it is undefined so I have to define it as this, "private int mId;"

totally lost on this one. the code where I got this is shown below.

mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());

```
 ButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  private int mId;

// anonymous inner class override for on click
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CoverFlowExample.class);
     MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);



     NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MainActivity.this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());


}
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the unique Id used to identify notifications for later manipulation purposes. By default its having value `0`.

If you dont care to retrieve it later for altering, then you dont even need to do `private int mId`, simply set any value when notifying, for example:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(123, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a unique id for the notification you are about to show, so you can later remove or update the notification.

The id is unique in the context of the app, so if you make two apps and use the same id android still knows the difference.

See: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int, android.app.Notification)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)

**From the developers site:**

**id:** An identifier for this notification unique within your application.

Rolf